# Can I use more than one @Id annotation in an Entity?

Tags: jpa, jpa-2.0

I want to define a table where the entire record is the primary key.   The table has two columns which are references to other entities.

```
@Entity
public class ProtoList implements Serializable {

  @Id
  @ManyToOne ProtoObject  listID;

  @Id
  @OneToOne  ProtoObject  po;
```

ProtoObject is an entity whose @Id is a regular generated Long.

The resulting relational data structure is intended allow any ProtoObject to be associated with an arbitrarily long List (actually a Set) of ProtoObjects.   So the two table columns are just two Longs, always unique.

Will this work or do I have to define an @IdClass or something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some experimentation I discovered that it was indeed necessary to use an **@IdClass** annotation.  What is interesting is that in the Entity itself I have the **@ManyToOne** and **@OneToOne** annotations to create relational links to **ProtoObjects**, but in the IdClass the corresponding fields are inferred from the **ProtoObject**'s own ID field.

So the result is:

```
@Entity
@IdClass(ProtoListKey.class)
public class ProtoList implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @ManyToOne ProtoObject  listID;

    @Id
    @OneToOne  ProtoObject  po;
```

And the key is:

```
public class ProtoListKey {

    private Long listID;

    private Long po;
```

The primary key of **ProtoList** is **Long** so this works.  The entire record is the primary key which is what I wanted.  Lesson learned.